# How to check who called the function in PHP?

Tags: php, debug-backtrace

It is any other method than `debug_backtrace` to check who called the function? I'm working on modular system and i like to control which module can have access to specific function/variable from the 'core' function set. `debug_backtrace` works perfect for me but i'm not very sure if i want to use it in production.

Comment: `debug_backtrace` is created for debugging. You should use `private`, `protected` and `public` which were designed for tell other objects and classes how can they access to each other.

Comment: @barell i know how to use `private`, `protected` and `public` but how i can check what module calling the function so i can decide to allow or reject it?

Answer (score 0):

Use an Object Oriented (OO) approach instead.

Using `debug_backtrace` for this is wrong, its for debugging.

You should use OO to restrict functionality.

For example if you have some modules `Customer`, `Product` and `User` then you can have each one of these extend a different class;

```
class Customer extends Admin_Module

class Product extends Public_Module

class User extends Registered_User_Module
```

You can also use `public`, `private` and `protected` statements to stop access from child classes or other completely different classes.

Comment: this NOT helped me at all ;-( i'm using OO but i don't know how to deny access for example `modules/customer/*.php` to access `$core->getPassword()`. With `debug_backtrace` i'll just check `debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 1)[0]['file']` and job done! I'm looking for 'PROPER' way to do that same functionality.

Comment: Its not helped your approach because your approach is wrong. Step back and take the right approach then OO will be helpful.

Comment: extending a class not give the main class to control who can access it, this way can any module extend the core module and see or not see - depends on the core function definition. what i want is for example any module from /modules/system/ to have access everywhere and /modules/custom/ just to few functions from the core....

Comment: Perhaps edit your original question and explain your implementation of modules. At the moment I do not know if a module is something a user logged into a CMS interacts with or if a module is code taken from GitHub that anyone can see/use.

Comment: i dont know how to re-word my question ;-( i just need to know who calling the function - best is to know the actual file name how i can see with `debug_backtrace` if its not possible is ok - i can think about something else and stop wasting the time with this option - just need to know if its or its not any other option how to do that